# Is it possible to setup a redirect in a PHP file which is guaranteed to work?

Tags: php, redirect, captcha, recaptcha, shtml

I want to make a call to/include a PHP script which would force a re-direct to another page. (The other page will contain a captcha and will re-direct back if entered correctly).

**I need the most reliable PHP redirect code possible**, so no one can escape/avoid it. If the redirect fails then the rest of the page will be shown and that's *not* what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No.

A redirection can be avoided if someone is actively seeking to avoid it or is using a browser which doesn't handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable is probably issuing:

```
header('Location: http://example.org');
exit;
```

Although rare a browser might choose not to follow the redirect though and as far as I know you will not find a way of redirecting the user that is guaranteed to work if they actively seek to escape it.

Like I say though it would be a rare browser that did not recognise or accept a `Location` header and a user would have to actively disable it some how. It is part of the original HTTP spec after all.

Comment: I am trying to block crawlers/scrapers so this could be a person actively trying to steal content so they might "actively seek to escape it"

Comment: @AdamLynch You need to take a different tack then. You cannot force the user to redirect without their permission. I would suggest that you set it to `exit()` or wrap the whole lot in an if/else to prevent them getting to stuff you don't want them to scrape. My code above will still work for you as it does exit execution after requesting the redirect so even if the redirect is ignored they will not see anything.

Comment: I know what you're saying. But I don't want to have to change all the .shtml files into .php files. So in shtml can I include the PHP file and store the result in a variable? 
  If so, then I could get the PHP script to echo 1/0 and then in the SHTML I can test if it's 1 then show the content, else show a captcha. 
  
  But don't know if this can be done. Because the shtml probably can't process the captcha when entered, unless I redirect upon entering the captcha, which would work

Comment: @AdamLynch sorry but I do not know enough about the capabilities of SSI to help you any further. I always try to get my codebase running the same language for maintainability. If it is possible at all that is the direction I would go in from here.

Comment: You could use the web server's technology (e.g. mod_rewrite) to redirect every request to a PHP file which validates the user and then redirects valid users to the requested file using a variation of @Treffynnon's code. Can provide an example if required.